# javascript - why is this element non-visible on cnn.com?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a chrome extension that highlights certain parts of webpages. I need to decide which elements are visible for the user. My current filtering logic checks these properties:

```
visibility, opacity, getBoundingClientRect dimensions.
```

These properties recognize most cases, I still find exceptions. e.g. the ul element with the class "quick-links" on the main page of cnn.com

This element has no obvious property that makes it invisible. Why is this element non-visible? is there any way to programmatically recognize this scenario?

Comment: What kind of styles are applied to the `quick-links` class? Without knowing that it's impossible to say what's causing it. You may also look into the z-index value.

Comment: opacity is zero on the parent element: `.more-mega-nav`

Comment: `function isHidden(el){
    if(el.tagName == 'BODY') return false;
    else if((el.style['display'] == 'none') || (el.style['visibility'] == 'hidden')) return true;
    else return isHiddenField(el.parentNode);
}`

I've used this before. Basically, you might need to look at parent elements, not just the element itself, and going up the DOM until you reach the body tag. A child element may be visible, but hidden due to a parent element.

The code may not help you here since you're doing an chrome extensino, but the idea might.

Comment: There are more ways to make elements invisible though: `position:absolute` with x/y out of the page, `z-index` negative and something in front of it, `transform: scale(0,0)` or `transform: matrix(0,0,0,0,0,0)`, `clip-path`, ...

Comment: @neilsimp1 That's way too basic to be useful for anything.

Comment: @Nit I'm not suggesting he uses the code. It's just the idea - the ul itself might not have any CSS making it hidden from the user, but any of it's parent elements might

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the quick-links container `<div class="more-mega-nav">` has the following properties, which make its children invisible to the user:

```
.more-mega-nav {
    opacity : 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It looks like `overflow: hidden` is the deciding factor, as the browser clips any child content that extends beyond the parent's `width` and `height`.